# Invalid conversion error over C and C++

Tags: c++, c

This my code.

```
struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

 struct MemoryStruct *mem = &state->characters;

  mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + len + 1);
```

When I run this code in 'C' and compile it by gcc, I didn't get any error.

But same code, I run in C++ and compile it by g++, I am getting error as

> error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Why It did give error in C++ and not giving error in C

Comment: Because `C` is not the same as `C++`

Comment: Please search within SO, this topic is rather well covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)  and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc). In C casting `malloc` "family" result is _type redundant_, whereas in C++ it isn't.

Answer (score 9):

> Why It did give error in C++ and not giving error in C

Because the rules of these languages are different. In this particular case, the difference is that C++ does not allow a conversion from `void*` to `char*`, whereas C does. That is what the compiler error is telling you.

Answer (score 3):

C++ give an error on this because there is no implicit conversion from void* to char* (at least in recent compilers).

If you want this code to compile in C++, you must cast to the right type:

```
mem->memory = static_cast<char*>(realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + len + 1));
```

or, if you want to keep C compatibility:

```
mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + len + 1);
```

But if you switch to C++, it is better to use C++ objects, like `std::vector` which will do the realloc for you.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you need to cast the values returned by `malloc` and friends:

```
 mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + len + 1);
```

Comment: No, in C++ you shouldn't use malloc to begin with, because it isn't compatible with `new` and `delete`. Preferably you should use a container class which handles the allocation internally. And if you for some reason still use `realloc`, you also need to cast the first parameter, if it is not `void*`, which it isn't in this case.

Comment: @Lundin I don't agree with your last statement. Explicitly casting a pointer to `void*` would be pointless.

Comment: @user2079303 Tough luck then, because C++ requires it.

Comment: @Lundin no it doesn't. See `[conv.ptr]/2` (of n4582 in case the numbering has changed)

Answer (score 1):

Simple is that C and C++ are both different Languages C inspire structs however C++ inspire struct as well as Object oriented paradigm in your case c have ability to convert void* to char* builtin property but c++ dont have this type of property c++ cant convert void* to char* so thats why compiler throw an error.